# Unable to attach to Azure App Service from Visual Studio 2019 Community edition

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service which hosts my Web Api solution. Sometimes, when there's a production issue which can not be reproduced on local environment, I usually attach a Visual Studio 2019 (community edition) debugger to that live instance.

For some reason, now it has stopped. When I try to attach the debugger by making a reference to Cloud Explorer > Pay As You Go > App Services > my-app-service (right-click and Attach Debugger) I get the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named '************************.azurewebsites.net'.  The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated.

at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions, CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount, IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase`1.ConnectToServer(String site, String user, String password)
```

I have no idea why is that. Tried to logout/login from my Azure account, also tried to restart the app service oh Azure but still nothing. Also tried to re-deploy the app but again nothing.

Comment: This could be due to an issue identified on App Service with VS 2019. 
The next App Service update should fix this. Currently available workarounds are to use VS 2017 or VS 2022. Side note, certain regions receive update sooner - [App Service update cycle](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/01/18/Demystifying-the-magic-behind-App-Service-OS-updates.html)

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried to remote debug the Azure App service from VS 2019 Community Edition, got the same error.

Tried the below approaches:

***Approach 1:***

In Visual Studio => View => Cloud Explorer => Select your App Service => Right click and Attach Debugger.

Got the below error.

[image]

***Approach 2:***

In VS => Debug tab =>  Attach to process.
In Connection target enter the deployed URL name without ***https***
Ex: `YourWebAppName.azurewebsites.net`

[image]

- It asks to enter the credentials. In Deployed Azure Web App=> click on Get Publish profile, there you will find the username name and password.

**Error :**

[image]

***Approach 3:***

In Publish window => Hosting => Attach Debugger
[image]

[image]

[Reference Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2019#configure-ports-for-remote-debugging)

If you still face issue after checking all the approaches, you can report the issue.

You can follow the [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/8455) link for further updates.